# Wildfly server:Partial Content and Range Requests

Tags: http, jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

Is there a way for wildfly server support http range header?
We are requesting file for server with http get and http header "Range: bytes 200-400"

The files that served from apache tomcat server responds http status code 206 and partial file content but wildfly server responds same request with http status code 200 and all file content. Since we are using big files it becomes a problem to transfer and seek file.
Is there any way to make wildfly support partial requests via configuration, plugin, module or a servlet code?

I am open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

We are using: wildfly 8.0.1 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for range requests was [added](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/commit/01273cd513ca90031f6be9f8bfb1247cb481b709) to undertow(web server used in WildFly) in version 1.2.

Version 1.2 included in WildFly 9.

WildFly 9 CR1 is out, with .Final version coming in few days.

so in short, upgrade to WildFly 9