# Does Wildfly 9.* support range-request?

Tags: jboss, http-headers, httprequest, wildfly

Supposedly range-request is supported in wildfly 9.x(undertow) server as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383656/wildfly-serverpartial-content-and-range-requests) .. but is not working in my case as you can see below.
Does anyone knows if it really works on wildfly and how do i make it work?

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080/stairs.mp4
 
HTTP / 1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Nov 2015 13:35:29 GMT
X-Powered-By: Undertow / 1
Server: WildFly / 9
Content-Type: video / mp4
Content-Length: 2890554
Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 17:29:53 GMT
```

Comment: I'm not expert, but don't you have to add the `Content-Range` header to your request? e.g. `range bytes=1-3`.

Comment: Even though the server was supposed to respond with `Accept-Ranges: bytes` in the header, as you can see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/), i have tried to specify the bytes range using, `curl -I -r 20-40  http://localhost:8080/stairs.mp4` or `curl --header "Range: bytes=20-40"  http://localhost:8080/stairs.mp4`, but got the same response mentioned on the original post.